# Azure Media Services web playback options

Tags: c#, azure, streaming, media-player, azure-media-services

What options do I have for browser playback of streaming content from WAMS (Windows Azure Media Services).

I need to ensure I have dynamic/adaptive streaming. Targeting primarily browsers (Flash or HTML5). Any additional client coverage is great, but not required.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of information regarding player frameworks and other sdk's for streaming content from WAMS can be found here: [Developing Windows Azure Media Services Client Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn223283.aspx)

Not sure if the following information is any use to you, but it shows the MPEG-DASH preview in WAMS which might be useful! [MPEG DASH preview from Windows Azure Media Services](http://blog.johndeutscher.com/2013/06/10/mpeg-dash-preview-from-windows-azure-media-services/)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using JWPlayer for the time being to save writing a Flash player.
All the information around encoding presets/job creation came from:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-549

Mingfei Yan (http://mingfeiy.com/) has a lot of resources on Azure Media Services including a number of example projects for end-to-end.